# How to load an external file from disk in adobe air? (Android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I want to load `/mnt/sdcard/audio.mp3` on Android and `C:\Users\username\Documents` on Windows

This code works on Windows

On Android `try_add_callbacks` is never called and no error message is displayed in header

```
try
{
    header.text="???";
    header.text=File.documentsDirectory.nativePath;

    var sound:Sound;
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,try_add_callbacks);
    sound.load(new URLRequest(File.documentsDirectory.nativePath+"/audio.mp3"));
}
catch(error:Error)
{
    header.text=error.errorID+" "+error.message;
}
```

I use `AIR 3.4 for Android`

Comment: a Sound object needs a url not a nativepath.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.documentsDirectory.nativePath` should be replaced with `File.documentsDirectory.url`

The app worked on Windows because it can recognize native path as url.

Thanks to [BotMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491257/botmaster)!